# How to read `synchronizeTabs` flag in a Firestore instance

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a library to be used with Firestore which that handles a local data store for the developer.

There is a slight difference in logic I need to implement depending wether or not the developer has enabled `synchronizeTabs` or not:

```
await firestore.enablePersistence({
  synchronizeTabs: true
})
```

The developer passes the Firestore instance to my library, but my question:

- How can I read the `synchronizeTabs` setting -- wether it's enabled or not -- based on the Firestore instance the developer passes to my library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a public API to read the value of that property. You'll have to either ask your users to enable persistence through your API, or make an additional call to your API after enabling persistence.

I think it could make a valid feature request though, so I'd recommend filing it on the relevant SDK repo. The feature has been [requested](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1577) before, but that was locked.